# Difference between scikit-learn and sklearn (now deprecated)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scikit-learn

On OS X 10.11.6 and python 2.7.10 I need to import from sklearn  manifold. 
I have numpy 1.8 Orc1, scipy .13 Ob1 and scikit-learn 0.17.1 installed.
I used pip to install sklearn(0.0), but when I try to import from sklearn manifold I get the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/**init**.py", line 57, in
>        from .base import clone   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in
>        from .utils.fixes import signature   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/**init**.py", line
>   10, in      from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32   File
>   "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash
>   (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029) ValueError: numpy.dtype has the
>   wrong size, try recompiling.

What is the difference between scikit-learn and sklearn?  Also, 
I cant import scikit-learn because of a syntax error

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You might need to reinstall `numpy`. It doesn't seem to have been installed correctly.

`sklearn` is how you type the scikit-learn name in python (only the latter should be installed, the former is now deprecated).

Also, try running the standard tests in scikit-learn and check the output. You will have detailed error information there.

---

As a side note, do you have `nosetests` installed? Try: `nosetests -v sklearn`. You type this in bash, not in the python interpreter.

Comment: Thank you Vinay87.  Reinstalling latest versions of numpy and scipy solved the problem.  Thanks also for explaining about sklearn.

Comment: But sklearn and sckit-learn are two different python modules. can you tell what is the difference

Comment: No, they are the same.

Comment: There are not exactly the same.  One point out on the over, this is different from being the same.
The description of the sklearn project is "Use scikit-learn instead.". This is for a reason. By using sklearn you loose any control you could have about the version.

Answer (score 93):

Regarding the difference sklearn vs. scikit-learn:
The [package "scikit-learn"](https://scikit-learn.org) is recommended to be installed using `pip install scikit-learn` but in your code imported using `import sklearn`.

A bit confusing, because you can also do `pip install sklearn` and will end up with the same scikit-learn package installed, because there is a "dummy" [pypi package sklearn](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/) which will install scikit-learn for you.

From [this thread](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8215#issue-201818378):

> scikit-learn is in install_requires of sklearn setup.py so you do
>   end-up with scikit-learn installed

[So](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8215#issuecomment-273766485):

> At the end, `pip install sklearn` or `pip install scikit-learn` ---
>   apart from the annoying `sklearn (0.0)` showed in the `pip list` ---
>   will install the latest available build from PyPI.

Answer (score 14):

As of Dec. 1, 2022 you have to use `scikit-learn` in pip requirements files as `pip install sklearn` is now deprecated.

source: https://github.com/scikit-learn/sklearn-pypi-package

Answer (score 2):

> The 'sklearn' PyPI package is deprecated, use 'scikit-learn'
> rather than 'sklearn' for pip commands.

Hereafter sklearn won't available for pip install from the latest versions. So it is better to start scikit-learn

**Reason for the deprecation:**

sklearn package on PyPI exists to prevent malicious actors from using the sklearn package, since sklearn (the import name) and scikit-learn (the project name) are sometimes used interchangeably. scikit-learn is the actual package name and should be used with pip

Please check this [link](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn/#:%7E:text=Reason%20for%20the%20deprecation%20sklearn%20package%20on%20PyPI,pip%2C%20e.g.%20for%3A%20pip%20commands%3A%20pip%20install%20scikit-learn) for further info

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem when uploading my project on Google Cloud. The error log said

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py"
.......ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

The solution as said above worked.
**Changed 'sklearn' to 'scikit-learn'** in my **requirements.txt**

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.