# python script that imports matplotlib succeeds butfrozen binary of script fails

Tags: python, matplotlib

My script needed to import `numpy`, `sklearn`, and `matplotlib` but I couldn't install sklearn.  A very helpful response to my question http://https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733220/difference-between-scikit-learn-and-sklearn explained that I needed to reinstall numpy.  Using pip to update numpy failed because OS X 10.11 SIP prevented uninstalling the current numpy.  The very helpful answer to a question about pip and SIP by mfripp http://https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209572/how-to-use-pip-after-the-os-x-el-capitan-upgrade provided a detailed solution to the problem.  I followed those instruction exactly and used `pip` to reinstall `numpy`, `matplotlib`, `scipy` and `sklearn` for all users.

When I ran my completed script using the command

> python DistMatPlot.py Random10A.matrix Random10A.pdf

the script ran perfectly, writing all expected output files.

However, I always saw:

> "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273:
>   UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This
>   may take a moment.   warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font
>   cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')"

which I had never seen with other matplotlib scripts before updating numpy, matplotlib, etc.  The 2 second delay was only mildly annoying.

I compiled a frozen binary using pyinstaller and during the compiling I got several messages similar to that above.
The resulting frozen binary run failed with the command:

> ./DistMatPlot Random10A.matrix Random10A.pdf

produced the following:

> /var/folders/8x/7_zp_33h8xj6td0059b72p9h0000gp/T/_MEIhIysTV/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273:
>   UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This
>   may take a moment. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 13, in    File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 389, in load_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 114, in    File "matplotlib/backends/**init**.py", line
>   32, in pylab_setup   File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 389, in load_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 24, in    File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 546, in load_module
>       module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, ext_tuple) RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X
>   backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not
>   installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more
>   information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please
>   either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other
>   backends. If you are Working with Matplotlib in a virtual enviroment
>   see 'Working with Matplotlib in Virtual environments' in the
>   Matplotlib FAQ DistMatPlot returned -1

I have looked at similar questions and tried their suggested solutions to no avail.

(1)  Why does matplotlib need to rebuild a font cache each time it is run?

(2)  Why does the frozen binary fail when the script itself succeeds?  Do I need some additional option other than -F when running pyinstaller?

Comment: Did you consider using [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which makes it much much easier to install common software (offering binaries)? As i'm not an OS X user i can't give other tips here, but i observe many many install/compilation problems on OS X compared to Linux (regarding complex software needing C++, Fortran and co.). Regarding matplotlib: it's doing the font-cache thing only once!

Comment: Did you get any solution for "Why does matplotlib need to rebuild a font cache each time it is run?"

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the frozen binary turned out to be "RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework."

Several posts discussed that issue and suggested adding these two lines before "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt":

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

That did not work, but this slight modification did work:
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

I suspect that 'Agg" may be specific to either OS X or to the version of python that is included with OS X 10.11

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller can have problems compiling some scripts, particularly if the use either the scipy or matplotlib modules.  Compiling appears to succeed, but the compiled script may fail to execute.  If the error message indicates that a module, e,g, scipy.stats, could not be found try compiling with the hiddenimport option:
pyinstaller -F --hiddenimport=scipy.stats --hiddenimport=_sysconfigdata  GrowthRates.py

When compiling scripts that use scipy or matplotlib Anaconda python helps a lot:
OSX:    python27Env
Windows:  Use Anaconda python
Linux:  Use Anaconda python