# Install sklearn or scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

To create a python environment for NLP,
I installed some packages as follows:

```
    • Gensim
    • Jellyfish
    • NetworkX
    • NumPy
    • NLTK
    • pyLDAvis
    • PyTorch
    • scikit-learn
    • spaCy
```

However, when installing `spaCy` using the following codes:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

I encountered with an error:

> pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
> pyldavis 3.3.1 requires sklearn, which is not installed.

Since I have already installed scikit-learn, I wonder if I need to install sklearn?
And what is the difference between scikit-learn and sklearn?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between scikit-learn and sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733220/difference-between-scikit-learn-and-sklearn)

Comment: @JonahG Hey! I found this post as well, but I still don't understand why I got that error.